# Binary file size change(reduced) when edit a block of that file

Tags: c, file, filesystems, binaryfiles, fwrite

Im making some tests to create a File System, i've created a Virtual Disk, with a format of 20 blocks of 512 bytes, and every file or directory is going to be stored in 1 of that blocks. Total size of Virtual Disk is 10.2 Kb, but when im trying to edit one of 20 blocks, total size of Virtual Disk is reduced.

F.E. If im editing block 5, the size of my Virtual Disk changes to 3.1Kb (512*6). It seems that when i use fwrite() function to write a block, Virtual Disk is formated to the size of the position of the block im editing.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Format_VDisk (int numberOfRecords,FILE *aStream);
void WriteBlock (int i, char *blockAddr,FILE *aStream);
void ReadBlock (int i, char *blockAddr,FILE *aStream);

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512 

int main()
{
    FILE *aStream;
    char command[10];   
    printf("Command:");
    scanf("%s",command);    
    if(strcmp(command,"init")==0)
    {
        aStream=fopen("VDisk","w+b");
        Format_VDisk(20,aStream);
        fclose(aStream);
    }
    else if(strcmp(command,"write")==0)
    {
        aStream=fopen("VDisk","w+b");
        char block[BLOCK_SIZE];
        memset (block, '1', BLOCK_SIZE);
        WriteBlock(5,block,aStream);
        fclose(aStream);
    }   
}

void Format_VDisk (int numberOfRecords,FILE *aStream)
{
    char block[BLOCK_SIZE];
    memset (block, '0', BLOCK_SIZE);
    WriteBlock (numberOfRecords - 1, block,aStream);    
}

void WriteBlock (int i, char *blockAddr,FILE *aStream)
{
    if(aStream!=NULL)
    {
        fseek (aStream, i * BLOCK_SIZE, SEEK_SET);      
        fwrite (blockAddr,BLOCK_SIZE, 1, aStream);          
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: He might find it useful to read [manpage for fopen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen). Especially the part explaining "w+" option. _The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated._ This means the file is not truncated by `fwrite` but by `fopen`. And `fwrite` enlarges it again to some extent.